# What is the first use of the term "Middle-earth" in Tolkien's works?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, middle-earth

Tolkien was writing stories set in his legendarium before a lot of his concepts and nomenclature was finalized.

### What was the first of Tolkien's writings to use the term "Middle-earth"?

Comment: @WadCheber Not to put anyone down, but IMO Apollo's answer has three problems: 1)It cites unreliable sources. 2)It doesn't provide any evidence that Annals of Valinor was the *first* work. 3)It fails to mention Ambarkanta, which may have been the earlier work.

Comment: Just because you had the answer you liked best doesn't mean others don't deserve recognition for their efforts. People get to spend their rep however they please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Both "Ambarkanta" & "Annals of Valinor", but it's unknown which one came first.

As per Christopher Tolkien (Tolkien's son and literary executor), the first works of Tolkien's to include the term *Middle-earth* were the ***Ambarkanta*** and the ***Annals of Valinor***.

> **"Middle-earth" is first found in the Ambarkanta and in the Annals of Valinor, which belong to the same period but cannot be dated relative to one another.**
>   <sub>(*Christopher Tolkien - The Shaping of Middle-earth (HoME4) - Commentary on the Ambarkanta*)</sub>

Both of these writings can be found in volume 4 of *The History of Middle-earth*.

> Above the Earth lies the Air, which is called Vista, and sustains birds and clouds. Therefore it is called above Fanyamar, or Cloudhome; and below Aiwenore or Bird-land. But this air lies only upon **Middle-earth** and the Inner Seas, and its proper bounds are the Mountains of Valinor in the West and the Walls of the Sun in the East.
>   <sub>(*The Ambarkanta - The Shape of the World*)</sub>
>
> In the Valian Year 1000, after the building of Valinor, and Valmar the city of the Gods, the Valar brought into being the Two Trees of Silver and of Gold, whose loom gave light unto Valinor.
>   But all this while Morgoth had dwelt in the **Middle-earth** and made him a great fortress in the North of the World; and he broke and twisted the Earth much in that time.
>   <sub>(*The Annals of Valinor (earliest version)*)</sub>

### Bonus: First published usage

The first published work of Tolkien's to include the term *Middle-earth* was ***The Lord of the Rings***.

> Yet it is clear that Hobbits had, in fact, lived quietly in **Middle-earth** for many long years before other folk became even aware of them.
>   <sub>(*The Lord of the Rings - Prologue*)</sub>

Comment: Why removing the (approximate) year the cited writings date back to? I think it's an important detail.

Comment: @lfurini - It wasn't essential towards answering the question, and it distracted from the actual answer. Maybe I'll reinsert it towards the bottom.

Answer (score 9):

### First usage.

> Tolkien began to use the term "Middle-earth" in the early 1930s in
>   place of the earlier terms "Great Lands", "Outer Lands", and "Hither
>   Lands" to describe the same region in his stories. "Middle-earth" is
>   specifically intended to describe the lands east of the Great Sea
>   (Belegaer), thus excluding Aman, but including Harad and other mortal
>   lands not visited in Tolkien's stories. Many people apply the name to
>   the entirety of Tolkien's world or exclusively to the lands described
>   in The Hobbit, The Lord of the Rings, and The Silmarillion. - [Source](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Middle-earth)
>
> Tolkien revised his chronology numerous times. The Annals of Valinor
>   were written in the early 1930s. - [Source_1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Arda#Summary) & [Source_2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shaping_of_Middle-earth)

The History of Middle-Earth is a 12 volumed series and in the 4th one (The Shaping of Middle-Earth) section 6 explains the earliest Annals of Valinor which was written in early 30s but published in the late 80s.

Following part is from The Annals of Valinor. You can find the entire text in the source.

> In the Valian Year 1000, after the building of  Valinor, and Valmar
>   the city of the Gods, the  Valar brought into being the Two Trees of
>   Silver  and of Gold, whose bloom gave light unto  Valinor.  But all
>   this while Morgoth had dwelt in the  *Middle-earth* and made him a great
>   fortress in  the North of the World; and he broke and twisted  the
>   Earth much in that time. [Source](http://library.globalchalet.net/Authors/Tolkien,%20J%20R%20R/J%20R%20R%20Tolkien%20Book%20Collection/The%20History%20of%20Middle%20Earth%20Vol_1-12/History%20of%20Middle-Earth%20-%2004.pdf)

The answer is entirely based on the power of deduction.

Comment: For future reference, I found this today: http://www.ew.com/article/2016/05/03/tolkien-annotated-middle-earth-map-oxford

Answer (score 4):

By an extention, Tolkien first referred to "middle-earth" in his 1914 poem entitled "The Voyage of Eärendel the Evening Star".

> Éarendel sprang up from the Ocean’s cup
>
> In the gloom of the **mid-world**’s rim;
>
> From the door of Night as a ray of light
>
> Leapt over the twilight brim,
>
> And launching his bark like a silver spark
>
> From the golden-fading sand;
>
> Down the sunlit breath of Day’s fiery Death
>
> He sped from Westerland.

This poem (which could be considered the first of Tolkien's legendarium writings) was inspired by an Anglo-Saxon poem *Crist* which actually used the term *middangeard* (middle-earth).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle-earth

http://www.tolkiensociety.org/2014/09/100-years-of-middle-earth

Comment: The OP was asking about the word, not the concept.

Comment: @ibid Just wanted to throw some information out there in case the OP or anyone else will find it relevant.